Get RequestedNodes of submitted job in HPC Pack 2019 Job Manager
I am configuring an HPC environment using Microsoft HPC Pack 2019. I want to know the RequestedNode parameter of a submitted job.
I know I can get it by exporting the xml of said job with Export-HpcJob, and then inspecting it to see what is the RequestedNode, but it seems unnecessary complex. Get-HpcJob does not return this value.
Thanks,
